# How to assign a new data point to a cluster?

Tags: clustering

I have a user dataset which contains fields like `['age','gender', 'computer_literacy', 'vision', 'colour_blind', 'education', 'font_size','colour']`.

I clustered this data and assigned the new cluster to the existing data. Now I want to know: how can I find a similar cluster for a new user?

As an example, if I am a new user I may submit only a few details like `['age', 'gender', 'computer_literacy', 'vision']` but still want to know to which cluster I belong.

What are the possible approaches to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose if  you use kmeans clustering then you can

1.train and  save the model using pickle

2.loa the model using pickle

3.pass your new sample as a vector to the predict function of the loaded model  object
model.predict([[0, 0], [12, 3]])

this will give you only one cluster label

4.if you want to get  top n clusters that the sample might belong to then take the cluster centers of your model as save it in a variable this will be list of list or matrix .

cc=kmeans.cluster_centers_

compute the similarity between your new sample and the cc matrix , rank the distances and yo will get n nearest clusters

Comment: This doesn't answer the part about having incomplete features

Comment: Can be add default data for incomplete one and cluster? Isn't is lead to a wrong clustering?